# JavaFX Choicebox does not populate

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am trying to populate a JavaFx Choicebox but it does not show text, however it does have the correct data in it. If I for example try to retrieve data from it and print it out it shows that the data is in the Choicebox.

```
@FXML
private ChoiceBox<String> shapes;

@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/canvas.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();

        Method[] m = AbstractFactory.class.getDeclaredMethods();
        ArrayList<String> shapeArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Method method : m){
            shapeArrayList.add(method.getName().substring(3));
        }
        shapes = new ChoiceBox<>();
        shapes.getItems().clear();
        shapes.getItems().addAll(FXCollections.observableArrayList(shapeArrayList));
        shapes.setValue("Test");

        primaryStage.setTitle("Paint!");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

FXML:

```
<ChoiceBox fx:id="shapes" layoutX="1.0" layoutY="174.0" prefWidth="150.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="444.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="174.0" />
```

When I start my application the Choicebox is blank and when clicked nothing happens.

Comment: The controller used with the fxml is not the same instance as the `Application` instance `start` is called for. You set the field for the `Application` instance that is launched though instead of using the instance created by `FXMLLoader`. This new instance is never added to a scene. BTW: You shouldn't do this: `shapes.getItems().clear(); shapes.getItems().addAll(FXCollections.observableArrayList(shapeArrayList));` Use `shapes.getItems().setAll(shapeArrayList);` instead to avoid unnecessary updates and list creations.

Comment: How do I get the correct instance?

Comment: After `loader.load()` use `loader.getController()`. I'd avoid using the application class as the the controller class btw. Note that using the initialize method may be an option in your case, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers

Comment: Thanks, I made a Controller class for the FXML and implemented Initializeable and that solved my problem.